# Having issues with populated inputs with fetched data: they are not updating on change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to fetch data from the database and then populate it in the appropriate fields. Then I want to be able to edit them and save the changes. But, I am having several problems with the text fields.

An image of the field already populated:

[image: This is the page I was working on]

If I use something like this:

```
const [lname, setLname] = useState("");

<TextField
  fullWidth
  label="Last name"
  name="lname"
  required
  value = { `${userDetails.lname}` || "" }
  onChange={(e) => setLname(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Then the text field becomes read-only, which I think is due to the fact that once I use `onChange`, it populates the field again using the value which is kind of a constant here.

If I change the `value` to `defaultValue`, I am able to update the value, but the initial value is `undefined`.

If I use something like this:

```
const [lname, setLname] = useState(userDetails.lname);

<TextField
  fullWidth
  label="Last name"
  name="lname"
  required
  value = {lname}
  onChange={(e) => setLname(e.target.value)}
/>
```

The initial `TextField` becomes empty.

The UserDetails is populated like this:

```
export default function ProfileDetails() {
  
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({});
  const { dispatch, isFetching } = useContext(UserContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:42690/api/users/user-details", {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}` },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data.fetchedUser);
        setUserDetails(
           (prevState) => ( { ...prevState, ...res.data.fetchedUser })
        );
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        toast.error("Failure to Load Profile");
      });
  }, []);
```

Can someone please help me solve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having different states, `userDetails` and `lname` (in case of last name) for one input, is not a good idea, and that's what is causing your issue.
I suggest you only use `userDetails`, and update it according to the input that's being changed, as an example, like so:

> Notice the comments I added

```js
export default function ProfileDetails() {
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    // The code that fetches data and updates userDetails goes here
  }, []);

  // One change handler for all inputs
  const handleInputsChange = (e) => {
    setUserDetails({ ...userDetails, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        label="First name"
        name="fname"
        required
        value={userDetails.fname}
        onChange={handleInputsChange}
      />
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        label="Last name"
        name="lname"
        required
        value={userDetails.lname}
        onChange={handleInputsChange}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `useEffect` to update your state when `userDetails.lname` value becomes available:

```
const [lname, setLname] = useState(userDetails.lname);

useEffect(() => {
  setLname(userDetails.lname);
}, [userDetails.lname]);

<TextField
  fullWidth
  label="Last name"
  name="lname"
  required
  value = {lname}
  onChange={(e) => setLname(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the issue; the only issue remaining is the text field getting overlapped with the form header field.

Comment: Please create a new question and add more details about the issue and a reproducible example if it is possible